# What type of partition GUID should I use for Linux with Btrfs?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, btrfs, sfdisk

I want to partition my disk in 2. One partition for UEFI and another for Btrfs where I will install Linux.

What type of [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) should I use? There are many available for Linux, see list available in sfdisk:

```
0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F  Linux swap
0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4  Linux filesystem
3B8F8425-20E0-4F3B-907F-1A25A76F98E8  Linux server data
44479540-F297-41B2-9AF7-D131D5F0458A  Linux root (x86)
69DAD710-2CE4-4E3C-B16C-21A1D49ABED3  Linux root (ARM)
4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709  Linux root (x86-64)
B921B045-1DF0-41C3-AF44-4C6F280D3FAE  Linux root (ARM-64)
993D8D3D-F80E-4225-855A-9DAF8ED7EA97  Linux root (IA-64)
8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908  Linux reserved
933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915  Linux home
A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E  Linux RAID
E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928  Linux LVM
4D21B016-B534-45C2-A9FB-5C16E091FD2D  Linux variable data
7EC6F557-3BC5-4ACA-B293-16EF5DF639D1  Linux temporary data
D13C5D3B-B5D1-422A-B29F-9454FDC89D76  Linux root verity (x86)
7386CDF2-203C-47A9-A498-F2ECCE45A2D6  Linux root verity (ARM)
2C7357ED-EBD2-46D9-AEC1-23D437EC2BF5  Linux root verity (x86-64)
DF3300CE-D69F-4C92-978C-9BFB0F38D820  Linux root verity (ARM-64)
86ED10D5-B607-45BB-8957-D350F23D0571  Linux root verity (IA-64)
BC13C2FF-59E6-4262-A352-B275FD6F7172  Linux extended boot
```

I'm in doubt if I must use `Linux filesystem` or `Linux root (x86-64)`.
If it's `Linux root (x86-64)` that I must use, is there an alias for it in sfdisk?

I'm going to use Btrfs, so I will probably not have a partition exclusively for home since I can have it in a subvolume to allow snapshotting of the whole data. Or is there an advantage in having a separate home partition?

---

**Update**

Currently fsdisk supports a limited number of aliases, see: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/1175

Answer (score 2):

You should choose the partition type according to the role the filesystem on the partition has. In your case, if you have only one Linux partition then that is your root partition, and the appropriate type is Linux root (x86-64).

The partition type is mostly not that critical, since other mechanisms are typically used to determine both the filesystem type (btrfs, etc.) and the partition role, for example the kernel command line parameter `root=`.

In pre-UEFI/GPT times, the partition type used to indicate the filesystem type, but even then this type was mostly ignored and instead the type was determined by detecting the filesystem or by explicitly mentioning the type in `/etc/fstab`.

On the other hand, if the correct type by role is used, it can be used to automatically choose what filesystem contained in the partition is to be used for. See [The Discoverable Partitions Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/) for more details.

I'm not sure if sdisk is aware of these codes. I always use gdisk (or sgdisk), as it has been written with GPT in mind.

Comment: Yes `sfdisk` is aware of those codes and supports GPT partitioning. All I need to know now is if there's an alias for `Linux root (x86-64)`.

Comment: Currently, sfdisk dos not appear to provide an alias for `Linux root (x86-64)`. You can use the full GUID, however.